# Rails: Query audit with json type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am using the [audited gem](https://github.com/collectiveidea/audited) in my app with a PostgreSQL db and I'd like to be able to query the `:audited_changes` attribute for all entries with a change in `:program_status`.  The change itself is irrelevant, I'd like all audits involving a change in `:program_status`.

**Audit Examples:**

```
#<Audit:0x007ff31789de80
  id: 11283,
  auditable_id: 2225,
  auditable_type: "Client",
  associated_id: nil,
  associated_type: nil,
  user_id: nil,
  user_type: nil,
  username: nil,
  action: "update",
  audited_changes: {"program_status"=>["full maintenance", "active"]},
  version: 21,
  comment: nil,
  remote_address: "::1",
  request_uuid: "a5a6a9f0-302a-443b-b09a-fd466557f757",
  created_at: Thu, 12 Jul 2018 17:49:40 EDT -04:00>

#<Audit:0x007ff31789de80
  id: 11284,
  auditable_id: 2226,
  auditable_type: "Client",
  associated_id: nil,
  associated_type: nil,
  user_id: nil,
  user_type: nil,
  username: nil,
  action: "update",
  audited_changes: {"program_status"=>["inactive", "active"]},
  version: 21,
  comment: nil,
  remote_address: "::1",
  request_uuid: "a5a6a9f0-302a-443b-b09a-fd466557f757",
  created_at: Thu, 12 Jul 2018 17:49:40 EDT -04:00>

#<Audit:0x007ff31789de80
  id: 11284,
  auditable_id: 2226,
  auditable_type: "Client",
  associated_id: nil,
  associated_type: nil,
  user_id: nil,
  user_type: nil,
  username: nil,
  action: "update",
  audited_changes: {"program_status"=>["full_maintenance", "limited_maintenance"]},
  version: 21,
  comment: nil,
  remote_address: "::1",
  request_uuid: "a5a6a9f0-302a-443b-b09a-fd466557f757",
  created_at: Thu, 12 Jul 2018 17:49:40 EDT -04:00>
```

It seems like I'd need to use a variation of `['{"a": {"b":"foo"}}'::json->'a'][2]`, I am just unsure how to use it in rails.

Answer (score 1):

What database are you using? If you are using MySQL the database field would actually be a serialized text column, so you can use something like

```
.where('audited_changes LIKE "%program_status%"')
```

If you use Mongo, something like

```
.where(audited_changes: {program_status: '$exists'})
```

If you use PostreSQL I think it supports json data types, I guess it has some specific syntax to query those kind of fields.

EDIT: for postgres

```
.where('audited_changes ? array[:keys]', keys: ['program_status'])
```

(check table 9-41 for OR and AND operations if you need more than one key https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-json.html)

Comment: Ran into an error: `PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  operator does not exist: json ? text[]
LINE 1: ...T "audits".* FROM "audits" WHERE (audited_changes ? array['p...`.  Also states `HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.`

Comment: I've never used postgresql, I was just reading the docs, sorry I can't help you any further.

Comment: as for your postgres edit, I think it should be `.where('audited_changes ?| array[:keys]', keys: ['program_status'])` (changed the operator from `?` to `?|`)

Comment: If you are using postgresl,  the answer varies based on if audited gem has been migrated to use jsonb data_type or is using the string datatype with YAML format.

For YAML

    .where("audited_changes LIKE '%program_status:%'")

For jsonb

    .where("(audited_changes->'program_status') IS NOT NULL")